# How to get Azure devops git repo folder name where user committed changes using powershell (Azure devops REST API)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I am working on script where I want to find out name of folder where user committed changes

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = ""
 
$OrganizationName = ""

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$UriOrga = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/"

$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "{Project Name}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepositoryID}/items?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json"
```

This is returning (It does return recent commit ID , Object ID but in path it returns only /)

> path=/;

Also with

```
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "{Project Name}/_apis/git/repositories/{REPO ID}/commits?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

It returns -

```
 author=; committer=; (Nothing for these values just blank)
```

Que - Am I using wrong API call ? How can I get Folder name , Committer name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the commit Folder name via commit ID

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Result:

[image]

And get the committer name via below API

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

get the committer name

I used postman to track these results, and I also tried powershell script, please check it.

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$connectionToken="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$CommitInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
Write-Host "CommitInfo = $($CommitInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @vito Where are you tracking these results? I tried deploying PS scripts locally and it gives me all blank values with adding commit ID as well.

Comment: Hi @megha  I have updated the answer and add the powershell script, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You use request without any filters. Try to add additional filters:

1. To search for items, you can add:

   - [scopePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#for-a-path)
   - [recursionLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#full-recursion-and-with-content-metadata)
2. To search for commits, you can add

   - [searchCriteria.itemVersion.version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#on-a-branch)
   - [searchCriteria.itemPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#on-a-branch-and-in-a-path)
   - [searchCriteria.user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-committer)